# Error al validar usuario en php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, vscode, xampp, php8

Tratare de ser lo mas conciso y claro posible, tengo un error que eh intentado solventar estos días pero simplemente no entiendo el porque, el contexto es que estoy actualizando el código de un php anterior a la versión de php 8, y me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo de validarUsuario.php:**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
require('../../conec.php');

$usuario=$_POST["usuario"];       $contrasena=$_POST["contrasena"]; $ip_usuario=""; //Agregue "$ip_usuario="";"
    
$sql = new  conectarMySQL();
$sql->conectar();   

$sql->consultar("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query="    SELECT us.rpe as RPE, zo.id_zona as IDZONA, us.privilegio as PRIVILEGIO, di.id_division as IDDIVISION
            From usuarios           as us
            Inner Join zonas        as zo
            Inner Join divisiones   as di
            Where rpe='{$usuario}' and password='{$contrasena}' and zo.id_division=di.id_division and zo.id_zona=us.id_zona and us.activo=1 limit 1 ";
            //Aqui modifique el SELECT a mayusculas para que se marcara la instruccion SQL

$sql->consultar($query);            

if($sql->numerodedatos() >= 1)  
{       
    if($row = $sql->obtendatos())   
    {
        session_name("CAP");
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["idZona"]=$row['IDZONA']; 
        $_SESSION['idDivision']=$row['IDDIVISION']; 
        $_SESSION['usuarioRPE']=$row['RPE'];                
        $_SESSION['userGroup']=$row['PRIVILEGIO'];  
        
        if      (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))         {   $ip_usuario=$_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];         }
        //elseif    (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))   {   $ip_usuario=$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];   }
        elseif  (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]))       {   $ip_usuario=$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];       }
        elseif  (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]))     {   $ip_usuario=$_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];     }
        elseif  (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"]))         {   $ip_usuario=$_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];         }
        else                                                {   $ip_usuario=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];            }
            
        $ip_usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($ip_usuario);
            
        $query="INSERT INTO logueos(rpe, fecha, hora, ip) VALUES ('{$row['RPE']}',NOW(), NOW(), '{$ip_usuario}')";
        $sql->consultar($query);
        
        echo "VALIDO";
    }       
}else{  echo "INVALIDO";    }

$sql->limpiaconsulta(); 
$sql->cerrarconexion(); ?>
```

**Conec.php:**

```
<?php class conectarMySQL {
//creamos las variables que vamos a utilizar en la conexion
var $servidor; //servidor
var $usuario; //usuario
var $password; //password
var $bd; //base de datos

//creamos las variables para las consultas
var $consulta; //aqu� se guarda las consultas que se realizan
var $enlace; //aqu� se almacena la conexi�n con la bd, s� se ha producido
var $resultado; //aqu� se guardan los datos que se generen de una consulta
var $datos; //aqui guardamos el numero de registros obtenidos en la consulta

//constructor, donde se inicializan las variables
var $nombre_campos=array();

//function conectarMySQL($servidor,$usuario,$password,$bd) 
//{    //    $this->servidor=$servidor;    //    $this->usuario=$usuario;    //    $this->password=$password;    //    $this->bd=$bd;    //}
function conectarMySQL()
{
    $this->servidor="localhost";        $this->usuario="root";        $this->password="";        $this->bd="cap"; //aqui quite el password original "tecnologias", recordatorio de ponerlo cuando finalice las pruebas
}

function modificaConectarMySQL($servidor,$usuario,$password,$bd) 
{
    $this->servidor=$servidor;
    $this->usuario=$usuario;
    $this->password=$password;
    $this->bd=$bd;
}

//conectamos con la base de datos
function conectar() 
{
    //se realiza la conexi�n a la base de datos 
    if($this->enlace=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cap")) //"localhost", "root", "", "cap" //$this->servidor,$this->usuario,$this->password,$this->bd
    {
        //se intenta acceder a la base de datos que deseeamos
        //if(mysql_select_db($this->bd,$this->enlace)) {  /*S� es correcta*/       } 
        //else { /*S� fallo mostrar mensaje error al acceder a la base de datos*/  echo "No se ha podido seleccionar la  BD";  }
    } 
    else 
    {  /*Si falla la conexi�n con la base de datos se muestra el mensaje*/ echo "No se ha podido conectar al servidor.";   }                 
}   

function consultar($query) {
    //aqu� se realizan las consultas a la base de datos
    $this->consulta=mysqli_query($this->enlace, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
}

function obtendatos() {
    //aqu� se obtienen los datos de la consulta
    $this->resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($this->consulta);
    return $this->resultado;
}   
/*
function mysqli_field_name($result, $field_offset)
{
    $properties = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $field_offset);
    return is_object($properties) ? $properties->name : null;
}

function obtencabeceraregistro( $query ){
    $numero_de_campos = numerodedatos();   
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $numero_de_campos; $i++ ) {        
        $campos[i] = mysql_field_name( $query, $i );        
    }      
    $this->$nombre_campos = $campos;
    return $this->$nombre_campos;    
}   
*/
function numerodedatos() {
    //aqu� se obtiene el numero de registros de la consulta
    $this->datos=mysqli_num_rows($this->consulta);
    return $this->datos;
}   
//cerramos la conexi�n con la base de datos
function cerrarconexion() {
    mysqli_close($this->enlace);
}
//libera el contenido que se encuentra en el atributo 
function limpiaconsulta() {
    if($this->datos>=1)
    {mysqli_free_result($this->consulta);}
}}?>
```

**ScriptLogin.js:**

```
$('document').ready(function () {
$("#formLogin").submit(function(e)  
{
    var contrasena=$("#contrasena").val();      var usuario=$("#usuario").val();        

    $.ajax(
    { 
        async: false,   type: 'POST',   url:  'validarUsuario.php',     data:  "usuario="+usuario+"&contrasena="+contrasena,
        success: function(respuesta)
        {               
            if ( $.trim(respuesta)=="VALIDO" )  {   window.location.href = "../../";     }
            else    if ( $.trim(respuesta) == "INVALIDO" )  
            {   alert("Usuario y/o contrase\u00F1a incorrectos.");  }       
            else
            {   alert("Ocurrio un error al tratar de iniciar sesi&oacute;n.");  }
        },  error: function(respuesta)                              
        {   alert("Ocurrio un error al tratar de iniciar sesión : "+ respuesta.statusText);     window.location.href = "login.php"; }
    });     
}); });
```

**Login.php:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8_spanish_ci" />
<title>Asistencia</title>
    <link href="../../css/styleLogin.css"           rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" media="screen">   
    <link href="../../css/styleMenu.css"                rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="../../css/styleGeneral.css"             rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" media="screen"> 
    <link href="../../css/styleVentanaModal.css"        rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" media="screen">                 
    <script src="../../js/jquery.min-1.7.1.js"          type="text/javascript"></script> <!--Agregado type="text/javascript"-->
    <script src="../../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"         type="text/javascript"></script> <!--Agregado type="text/javascript"-->
    <script src="../../js/scriptLogin.js"               type="text/javascript"></script> <!--Agregado type="text/javascript"-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="idcabecera" >
        <div>
            
            <div id="divTitulo">            
                    <div id="divTituloTexto">Control De Asistencias Y Puntualidad(CAP)</div>        
            </div>          
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div id="divContenido" aling="center">              
        <div id="divInicio"  >
            <div id="divCentrado">
                <form id="formLogin" action="../../" method="post"><!--form action="validar_usuario.php" method="post" name="acceso"  style="margin-top:10px;"-->
                    <h1>Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n</h1>
                    <br><br>
                    <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                    <input id="usuario"         type="text"     required="required" style="width:200px;" autofocus/>                    
                    <br><br>
                    <label for="contrasena">Contrase&ntilde;a:</label>
                    <input id="contrasena"      type="password" required="required" style="width:200px"/>
                    <br><br>
                    <input id="btnIniciar"      type="submit"   value="Iniciar" >
                </form>             
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>             
</body>
</html>
```

Se que si cambio lo que me esta marcando el error todo aparentemente se soluciona, ya que donde va la conexión podría poner: *"localhost", "root", "", "cap"*, pero aun así me deja sin poder acceder, cabe destacar que mi BD funciona correctamente y los datos coinciden, pero no he descubierto que es lo que tengo que cambiar para que funcione plenamente y me deje acceder a las otras interfaces (porque hay mas paginas que se acceden una vez pasas el login). Aqui el ejemplo de de lo que pasa si hago el cambio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se que los **arrays** marcan error y es porque no les he mandado el usuario y la clave, también marca *INVALIDO* porque no esta accediendo al login ya que es solo es el puro código de validarUsuario, pero como mencione esto no revuelve el problema ya que no me sigue dejando acceder a las demás pestañas con el Login.

En mi login pongo los datos correctamente pero simplemente me arroja que los datos son incorrectos, así que en resumidas cuentas mi preguntas es ¿hay algo que estoy haciendo mal, me falta una parte del código o las funciones que aparecen están mal implementadas?

Eso seria todo a grandes rasgos, puedo pasar mas capturas y código de ser necesario, si alguien pudiera iluminarme estaría agradecido, soy un poco novato en php.

Gracias por su atención. :)

Comment: Nadie te va revisar capturas de pantalla aqui, tienes que postear el codigo si quieres recibir ayuda

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ya lo edite.

Comment: Segun el error viene porque la conexion falla con la DB y ahi resulta nulo cualquier proceso subsiguiente, deberia primero probar que tu clase conecta con la DB

Comment: Puedes probar este metodo en tu clase y ver si te regresa?

Comment: # Test if DBNAME exists
  public function test_db() {
    $this->conx = new \mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    if ($this->conx->connect_errno) {
      error_log("Database test failed: " . $this->conx->connect_error );
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $this->conx->connect_error;      
      exit();
    }
    
    return $this->conx->select_db(DBNAME);
  }

Comment: El error que te devuelve PHP es un error con la DB "mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied"

Comment: Revisa ese usuario y revisa si localhost lo usas porteado "localhost:3306" por ejemplo  para acceder a la DB, confirma que root existe, tiene privilegios para hacer consultas y que no requiere password

Comment: Sobre lo que comentas ya hice pruebas y el accesos esta ahí, seguiré indagando al respecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según me parece, tu problema es que mandas el formulario por dos sitios al pulsar el botón `submit`. Uno mediante ajax, y otro como normalmente se haria, pues no estás evitando el comportamiento por defecto del evento `submit` en el formulario.

Al hacerlo de dos modos, estás obteniendo una nueva página con los errores, pues creo que da preferencia al comportamiento por defecto, y como tus **input** carecen de `name=` nunca son capaces de validar el usuario y contraseña.

Una posible solución es cambiar esto:

```
$("#formLogin").submit(function(e)  
{
```

por esto:

```
$("#formLogin").submit(function(e)  
{
    e.preventDefault()
```

pues al hacerlo impides el comportamiento normal del evento `submit` y sólo ejecutará lo que haya dentro de esa función.

Consulta [su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para más ayuda.

Otra solución es cambiar el `type="submit"` por  `type="button"` y filtrar el evento `click` en lugar del `submit` de ese elemento.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte! la verdad es que lo intente pero no funciono, siento que el error tiene mas que ver en el código de conec.php y validarUsuario.php, de alguna manera siento que la clase no se esta comportando de la manera que yo esperaría

Comment: Encontré el error, para resumir, en UserGroup en la columna de privilegios no estaba asignando correctamente su valor, después de corregir eso se soluciono de inmediato, además lo que comentaste sirvió para integrarlo a mi código!

Comment: Me alegro que lo encontraras. Si esta respuesta es válida para tu pregunta (y no esto otro del UserGroup que no tiene que ver con ella ni lo habias mencionado tampoco) te ruego que la marques como aceptada para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente de respuesta. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo cuando la respuesta soluciona tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por la info, lo hare de inmediato! soy nuevo en stackoverflow